# not able to fetch all category in opencart autocomplete admin

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I am not able to fetch all the categories when I click on Products->link. I have 11 categories and all categories have same 4 subcategory, but I am only able to see 5 categories. How can I see all 11 at the same time?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rajat did u try increasing the limit in admin -> catlog->category ?

Comment: admin/controller/catalog/filter.php 
I tried this and it didnt work

Comment: modify the /admin/controller/catalog/category.php file.
====================================================
`code`
 $filter_data = array(
            'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
            'sort'        => 'name',
            'order'       => 'ASC',
            'start'       => 0,
            'limit'       => 5  // Increase this to get more results in the autocomplete dropdown. 25 seems like a better value.
         ); `code`

Answer (score 0):

on admin/controller/category.php find this code

```
                'filter_name'  => $filter_name,

                'filter_model' => $filter_model,

                'start'        => 0,

                'limit'        => $limit

            );
```

And remove the start and limit values in array so the code will be like this

```
$filter_data = array(

                'filter_name'  => $filter_name,

                'filter_model' => $filter_model

            );
```